# How do you deploy a clojurescript reagent app?

Tags: clojurescript, reagent

Reducing the problem to the simplest form:

```
$ lein new reagent experiment
$ cd experiment
$ lein do clean, uberjar
$ cat >index.html <<EOF
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
    <link href="resources/public/css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body class="body-container">
    Hello World
    <div id="app">
      <script src="target/cljsbuild/public/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
EOF
```

Pointing the browser to localhost:5000 works when using 'foreman start', but does not when serving out of nginx. (Meaning, putting this directory in a directory served by nginx will load the css and js, will show "Hello World", but the javascript has errors.) The following two errors appear in the browser's console:

```
app.js:451 Error rendering component (in Vn)
(anonymous) @ app.js:451
app.js:471 Uncaught Error: Assert failed: Invalid Hiccup form: [nil]
 (in Vn)
(valid-tag? tag)
    at Mk (app.js:471)
    at Jk (app.js:473)
    at Dk (app.js:475)
    at Ik (app.js:470)
    at Mk (app.js:472)
    at Jk (app.js:473)
    at bk (app.js:449)
    at app.js:451
    at uj (app.js:428)
    at vj (app.js:429)
    at Tj (app.js:448)
    at t.render (app.js:451)
    at p._renderValidatedComponentWithoutOwnerOrContext (app.js:25)
    at p._renderValidatedComponent (app.js:25)
    at performInitialMount (app.js:25)
    at p.mountComponent (app.js:25)
    at Object.mountComponent (app.js:27)
    at performInitialMount (app.js:25)
    at p.mountComponent (app.js:25)
    at Object.mountComponent (app.js:27)
    at i (app.js:26)
    at r.perform (app.js:27)
    at u (app.js:26)
    at r.perform (app.js:27)
    at Object.batchedUpdates (app.js:26)
    at Object.a [as batchedUpdates] (app.js:27)
    at Object._renderNewRootComponent (app.js:26)
    at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (app.js:26)
    at Sk (app.js:476)
    at app.js:554
    at app.js:554
    at app.js:555
```

Comment: Which browser? Have you looked at the network tab to make sure that everything is in fact loading the same with nginx? How did you copy the files to the nginx directory. Perhaps you missed a file somehow or have a permissions issue.

Comment: Chrome. All is loading (see https://www.murphydye.com/exper/index.html). Usually use rsync to copy, but in this case ran the above commands inside the nginx directory, so didn't copy at all.

Comment: Can you try serving the same nginx directory using a simple python one-liner `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5001`. That will determine if something is wrong with the files/directory structure/permissions or if nginx is at fault.

Comment: Yes, and that works. (Btw, this is essentially the same as using foreman.)

Comment: I've done a couple of experiments on my side. I download the app.js from your webserver and tested that in my environment without problems so content corruption/modification is not the issue. I also tried running a python HTTPS server and that works so it's probably not an HTTP/HTTPS boundary permissions issue/difference. My next suggestion would be to change the optimizations settings from :advanced to :whitespace, removing the target directory and rebuilding. This will prevent code elimination/renaming (for easier debug of the error).

Comment: Thanks kanaka. Will try that. A bit more info: from my understanding an http server should be necessary. Going to file:///path-to-directory/exper/index.html should pull it up fine, but it exhibits the same error as nginx.

Comment: https://www.murphydye.com/exper/ is compiled with :whitespace, yielding a better stacktrace. Afraid it doesn't help me much though. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I believe something about your nginx configuration is breaking the clientside secretary routing. As you noted a similar error happens if you load the file from the filesystem (file://.../index.html).

One thing that the default reagent template doesn't provide is a default route for ".../index.html". I suspect that might help in the nginx case. I would add the following to src/cljs/experiment/core.cljs and rebuild:

```
(secretary/defroute "/index.html" []
  (session/put! :current-page #'home-page))
```

With that change, I was able to successfully load the page by serving it using the standard nginx docker container (and then browsing to localhost:5001):

```
docker run --name nginx -v `pwd`:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -d -p 5001:80 nginx
```

You might want to compare the default configuration of that nginx docker image to your own configuration to determine what the root cause of your issue is.

Comment: I like that idea but couldn't make it work either. The only modifications to the basic lein install posed in the question are: project.clj has whitespace optimization and pretty-print set to true, and the additional route you suggested. https://www.murphydye.com/experiment/

Comment: @BrianMurphy-Dye I tested with nginx locally via a standard nginx docker container and it worked. I updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Heh, was going to comment that I got it to work via a local nginx docker container too. My actual site is double proxied, once for a lets encrypt nginx container for https, which proxies to several other containers, one of which is for murphydye.com. You didn't note it in your answer, but adding the additional "/index.html" route as you previously suggested is needed for this to work. If you add that back, I'll accept your answer, and then see if I can work through the double proxy issue.

Comment: @BrianMurphy-Dye ah yes, I still had that in my version. I've added that part back to the answer. Glad you are on your way to getting it working.

Answer (score 0):

There were two problems here, both of which kanaka's help was instrumental in ferreting out.

1. the incoming url from nginx included "/index.html", for which there was not a secretary route. See kanaka's solution above.
2. the secretary routes assume urls are off of root. In my case, this app is one of many, so it resided in a subfolder at https://www.murphydye.com/experiment/index.html.

One solution for this is to modify #'current-page as such:

```
(defn current-page []
  [:div (or (session/get :current-page) #'home-page)])
```

This gets us to the home-page when nothing matches, and also solves problem #1 (we no longer need the additional defroute "/index.html").

I say "one solution" because as you click links, the url bar will again assume it is off of root, e.g., click the **about** link and the url bar will show **/about**, not **/experiment/about**. Everything works because it doesn't go to the server to load the erroneous url, but bookmarking it will not work. There is surely another way to handle this, but this solves both problems sufficiently for now.

Thanks again kanaka!